# Problem with firestore from react native app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, native

I am working with react native, i installed firebase with

```
npm install firebase
```

but when i try to user firestore with

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users')...
```

The error message is "firestore is not a function

I am using firebase  and the latest version of react native.

fire.js file

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "domaincom",
    databaseURL: "url",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "mess",
    appId: "appId"
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default fire;
```

register.js file

```
import fire from '../config/fire';

async _onRegisterPressed() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        try {
            await fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
                .then(() => {
                    fire.firestore().collection('users').add({
                        email: this.state.email,
                        fullName: this.state.fullName,
                        password: this.state.password
                    });
                });
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
            alert('Usuario Creado!');
        } catch (ex) {
            alert('Error creando el usuario');
            console.log("Error: "+ex);
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }
    }
```

Comment: try correcting the typoerror

Comment: The error was when writing this post, in my code is written correctly.

Comment: is `fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(` working?

Comment: Yes, that function is working

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing firestore correctly in your register.js file?

Try something like this. It always works for me.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

Also it is bad practice to import whole firebase using `import * as firebase from 'firebase';`

You must be getting warning in your console for the same.